# Spring in-memory cold start

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a REST API built using Spring Framework, and to improve performance on one of my endpoints I'm thinking of using an in-memory database for faster retrieval.

I need to handle 2 cases

1. Loading the in-memory database at startup (cold start)
2. Updating the data

For the second one, I'm thinking of just using Spring's scheduler to update the data at regular intervals.

But for the cold start, I don't know what would be the best solution because loading all the initial data could be a long process.

Comment: Load it asynchronously.

Comment: Were you thinking of loading the entire db at once, or just populating a cache lazily with each record as it is accessed while handling requests? Will the database always be small enough to fit in memory?

Comment: Do you want the data to be persistent or not? (i.e., is it OK if the data disappears when the webapp shuts down or should data be saved on disk?). If it's the second, then it might be better to use an on-disk database with an in-memory cache in front of it instead of an in-memory DB.

Comment: @HankD I was thinking of loading the entire db at once, and for now let's assume it's small enough to fit in memory

Answer (score 0):

The choice depends on your SLA. If you choose to finish populating it before the API becomes available, you are choosing to sacrifice availability for the sake of preventing delayed responses.  If you choose to make your API available while the db is populated asynchronously, you will sacrifice response time in your first few requests while the db is populated.  Which is most imperative in your SLA? uptime or response time?

If you will have a cluster of servers honoring requests, there is no advantage to optimizing uptime, because running servers will handle requests while your server takes its time to populate the db synchronously, and if you populated it asynchronously, your clients would experience unnecessary delays if the just-started server began taking on requests.

Consider also if a database is small enough to fit into memory (only an assumption for the sake of discussion, I know), it might not take long enough to load to make much of a difference.